# Snowflake - Java Script UDF calling Snowflake External function

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have an External function defined in Snowflake. I want to call that function in my JavaScript UDF function. Is it possible to do so?

Thanks

Comment: It would be interesting to know what's the actual use case - to see if there's a workaround

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you can't call any other UDF including external functions from a JavaScript UDF. You ***can*** call them from SQL UDFs and JavaScript stored procedures by executing them in a SQL statement.

You can also nest UDF calls, like `select function_1(function_2(my_value));`